# How prove this inequality $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+ab)\le 6$

Tags: inequality

> let $a,b,c> 0$ and such $a+b+c=3$
>
> show that
>   $$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+ab+bc+ac\le 6?$$

I can't find counterexample, maybe it is true. Then how prove it?

And I know
$$(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)\le 4,a+b+c=3$$
see:[Proving the inequality $4\ge a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+abc$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028027/proving-the-inequality-4-ge-a2bb2cc2aabc/1029193#1029193)
But this isn't useful

[image]

Comment: Notice that $a=0, b=15/8, c=9/8$ forms a counter example.

Comment: sorry,if $a,b,c$ postive numbers?

Comment: Doesn't matter. you can take $a \to 0$ that is very very small enough and $c=9/8-a$

Comment: Hello,I think if $a,b,c$ are postive numbers,this inequality is true

Comment: When $a = \frac{11}{6}, b = \frac{9}{8}, c = \frac{1}{24}$, RHS = $\frac{83261}{13824} > 6$. Over the admissible range of $a,b,c$, RHS seems to be bounded from above by $\frac{26\sqrt{13}+70}{27} \approx 6.064604931928285$.

Comment: @chinamath apparently the inequality is true if $a \le b \le c$ and $b \le 1$ ! :-)

Comment: @r9m,if $a\le b\le c,b\le 1$ I can prove it.

Comment: @chinamath okay ! nice :)

Comment: because we only use $(b-a)(b-c)\le 0$,then we have$$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a\le b(a^2+ac+c^2)=b(a+c)^2-abc$$,so $$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+ab+bc+ac\le b(a+c)^2+b(a+c)+(1-b)ac\le b(3-b)^2+b(3-b)+(1-b)\cdot(c+a)^2/4,0<b\le 1$$,then it is easy

Comment: @chinamath right ! that's exactly what I did there !! :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong! Try $c=0$ and $a+b=3$.

Comment: The OP asks for $a,b,c>0$. Anyway, in your case, the inequality becomes $a^2b+ab=ab(a+1)\leq6$, or $a(a+1)(3-a)\leq6$, and it would be wrong in a small interval around $a=1.9$. With a tiny positive $c$ instead of $0$, your counterexample works, so +1 for me. For example, $a=1.9, b=1.09,c=0.01$ will do.